# Prove the following: Let $n$ be an integer. If $2|n^2$, then $4|n^2$.

Tags: proof-writing

I came up with the following:

$2|n^2$ implies that $2|n*n$. We proved in class that if $q|b*p$, then $q|b$ or $q|p$. Therefore, if $2|n^2$, then $2|n$ or $2|n$.
So, $2|n$ implies $n=2k$, for some $k ∈ Z$. 
So, $n^2|(2k)^2$,
    $n^2 = 4k^2$, where $k^2 ∈ Z$.

So, if $2|n^2$, then $4|n^2$ as desired.

What do you all think?

Comment: Well if $n$ is odd, then $2\nmid n^2$ so you're done with that case.

Comment: Should it be "if $2\mid \color{red}{n}$ then $4\mid n^2$"?

Comment: See the statement is - *if* $2|n^2$ *then* $4|n^2$. You don't need to think about odd $n$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Have you done prime factorisation?  Assuming so, what are the properties of the exponents of the prime factors in the every factorisation of a square number?

Comment: Try adding the answer to this to your question: Is this a problem from a text, or from a class? If from a class, which one, and what theorems have they seen recently? If a text, which one? For example, are they in a context of abstract algebra, or number theory, or intro to proofs, or something else?  See this discussion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47930322#47930322

Comment: @Dave I think not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose not. Then $n^2=2\times (2m+1)$ for some positive integer $m$. But that means, $n^2=4m+2$. Which is a contradiction, as, any perfect square can leave remainder $0,1$ after division by $4$.

---

Here is a more satisfactory arument. A statement and it's [contrapositive statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) has same truth value. Here, the contrapositive statement of $2|n^2\implies 4|n^2$ is $4\nmid n^2\implies 2\nmid n$. So, if we can prove the contrapositive statement is true then we are done.

$$4\nmid n^2\implies 2\nmid n\implies 2\nmid n\cdot n  $$
So we are sone!

Comment: Is there any problem to understand this?

Comment: No. I think I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $2|n^2$, $n^2$ is even. Note that  $n^2$ is even if and only if  $n$ is even (in $\Bbb Z$). So  $n=2m $ for some  $m \in \Bbb Z$. Hence  $n^2=4m^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $2|m^2$ then it means its square root $m$ must be even, or else $m$ would be irrational. If it were odd then there would be no $2$ as part of its prime factors, so multiplying it by itself would not create an even number. We can define $n$ such that $2n=m$. Since $m^2=(2n)^2=4n^2$, then we can easily show $4|4n^2$ and therefore $4|m^2$.

Answer (score -1):

An import ant part of writing any proof is to determine from the outset what you can assume to be true.

If you can assume the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) then you have the unique prime factorisation of $n=p_1^{i_2}\cdot p_2^{i_2}\cdot p_3^{i_3}\ldots$

Then the prime factorisation of $n^2=p_1^{2i_2}\cdot p_2^{2i_2}\cdot p_3^{2i_3}\ldots$

Then since every exponent is even, the power of every prime factor of $n^2$ is either $1$ or a power of $p^2$, which generalises the result you need to every prime.

(In $2^3=8$, 2 is the prime, 3 is the exponent and 8 is the power).